# Two bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies

I have already written my thesis in LaTeX using the standard bibliography option and in the text they are cited with 1, 2 and so on. However, now I need to separate 11 articles from my original bibliography and cite them with [A1], ..., [A1]. What's the easiest and fastest way to do this?

Comment: Two bibliographies isn't hard: [Multiple bibliographies with biblatex](http://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/). As for printing out the articles with a different numbering scheme and a prefix, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Thank you. If you find out, please tell me. I need to solve the problem in less than a day!

Comment: You will be much more likely to get help which actually helps if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) i.e. a small document people can copy-paste-compile to play around with. No fun having to start a document from scratch, especially since I'm not at all clear whether such a thing would help because I don't know what you have done. [Which 'standard bibliography option'? What distinguishes the 11 from the rest? Which document class? Are you loading any packages affecting citations/bibliography?]